# Oil leak on engine top

Tags: engine, oil-leak

So I have a 07 Subaru Impreza wagon 2.5. It’s seems to have oil on top of engine behind power steering pump. It’s definitely oil and not tranny fluid. I checked oil pressure switch and it’s not coming from that.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where it might be coming from? All help greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you check the Pressure sensor.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what you do:

Purchase a 395 black light [like this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008133KB4) on Amazon.  Shine it all over the engine and see what it looks like, noting what is reflective and what is not.

Purchase [some automotive dye](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002M4G24U) and pour it into your crankcase through the oil fill neck.  Drive the car normally for a few days.

Check the engine again with the black light.  You should see a little fresh oil with the dye coming from the location of your leak.  If not, keep checking every few days of driving.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking of doing that. I’ll get to it this weekend and let you know my finds.

Comment: Please do.  We always like to hear about the outcome.